# Border-bottom not displaying at bottom of div when there is overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a [website](https://sweepsdb.com/) that displays several articles on a page. Here is the code for one of them.

```
<article class="post post-large ">
    <div title="Contest start date" class="post-date">
        <span class="day">14</span>
        <span class="month">Jul</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="post-content">
        <h2 class="font-weight-semibold text-6 line-height-3"><a class="contest_title" target="_blank" href="go/123456">TITLE <i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></a></h2>
        <h4 class="mb-1 text-4 font-weight-bold">Ends in <span class="text-color-secondary">7 Days 8 Hours</span></h4>
                                        <div class="scrollable visible-slider colored-slider has-scrollbar" data-plugin-scrollable="" style="max-height: 15em; height: 52px;">
            <div class="scrollable-content" tabindex="0" style="right: -17px;">
                DESCRIPTION
            </div>
        <div class="scrollable-pane" style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible; display: none;"><div class="scrollable-slider" style="height: 39px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);"></div></div></div>

        <div class="post-meta">
            <span title="Platform: Gleam"><img src="img/platforms/gleam.png"> </span>
            <span title="Author"><i class="far fa-user"></i> By <a href="#">SweepsDB</a> </span>
            <span><i title="Contest has referral option" class="fas fa-share-alt-square fa-lg text-primary"></i></span>
            <span title="End Date"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> July 21, 2022 </span>
            <span title="Countries"><i class="fas fa-globe-americas"></i> Canada</span>
            
            
            <span title="Report contest"><i class="far fa-flag"></i> <a data-id="123456" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#reportModal" class="report" href="#">Report</a></span>
            <span style="float: right;" class="d-block d-sm-inline-block float-sm-right mt-3 mt-sm-0"><a target="_blank" href="go/123456" class="btn btn-xs btn-light text-1 text-uppercase">Visit Contest</a></span>
            <span style="float: right;" class="d-block d-sm-inline-block float-sm-right mt-3 mt-sm-0"><a href="contest/X/123456" class="btn btn-xs btn-light text-1 text-uppercase">More Details</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

which looks something like this:
[image]

However sometimes on mobile layouts, the *More Details* and *Visit Contest* links are below the bottom border, like this:
[image]

The relevant CSS for `border-bottom` is:

```
article {
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

What do I need to change to have the bottom border show up at the true bottom of the `<article>`, even if there is overflow from other elements within the article?

Comment: If you want the border to show at the bottom even when overflowing, then why set a specific height (or max-height) in the first place. Maybe try removing the height from article, then the border would sit at the bottom because nothing would overflow.

Comment: @DanielBlack the div block that contains the `max-height` is for the description section. This does not affect the border on the bottom

Comment: You need to provide a proper [mre] that illustrates the issue, directly inside your question. (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878)